# Is there a common name for solids where $V = h \cdot A_t = h \cdot A_b$

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I'm trying to find a name which describes all solids which have these properties:

- $h = height$
- $A_{t} = top\ area$
- $A_{b} = base\ area$
- $A_{t} = A_{b}$
- $V = h \cdot A_t = h \cdot A_b$

Examples include Prisms, hence Cuboids and Cylinders.

If such a name doesn't exist, what would you call them?

Comment: I think the general name would be prism and then one would classify by base shape. So although it might sound strange one could call a cylinder a circular prism and a cube a square prism.

Comment: I believe cylinder or generalized cylinder is the term: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These surfaces are known as **generalized cylinders** and they show up in differential geometry. The base can be any shape, but there are a few cases that have their own names:

1. A **circular cylinder** is a cylinder with a circle as its base (This is the normal cylinder).
2. If the base is a ellipse, it respective cylinder would be called an **elliptic cylinder**.
3. If the base is a parabola, it's known as a **parabolic cylinder**.
4. If the base is a hyperbola, it's known as a **hyperbolic cylinder**.

Generalized cylinders can be made over any shape or curve. So under this general definition a cube would be a cylinder with a square base, and a square would be a cylinder with a line as its base. Even a line can be thought of as a cylinder with a single point as its base. Notice that your formulas still hold since the area of a point or line is $0$, so the volume is $0$ as well.

Comment: Thank you, especially for pointing out that the formula can be used on a square or a line.